# Making a Javascript click function for model objects formatted in Django Tables2 that shows related divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-tables2

I'm trying to make a Javascript function involving a django-tables2 table featuring model objects that will show relevant information when clicked. Here is the relevant code:

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ssn = USSocialSecurityNumberField(null=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    country = CountryField(default='US', blank=True)
    primary_phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, validators=[validate_email])
    background = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=BACKGROUND_CHOICES)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='south_plainfield')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

tables.py

```
class StudentListTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.TemplateColumn('''{{ record.first_name }} {{ record.last_name }}''', verbose_name=u'Name')
    manage = tables.TemplateColumn('''<a href="/students/update_student/{{ record.id }}">Update</a> / <a href="/students/delete_student/{{ record.id }}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>''')
    assign = tables.TemplateColumn('''<a href="/students/id={{ record.id }}/add_studentcourse">Courses</a> / <a href="/students/id={{ record.student_id }}/add_studentemployment">Employment</a> / <a href="/students/id={{ record.id }}/add_studentcounselor">Counselor</a> / <a href="/students/id={{ record.id }}/show_student_lists">Show</a>''')

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id', 'name', 'gender', 'ssn', 'email', 'primary_phone', 'created_at', 'manage', 'assign')
        row_attrs = {
            'id': lambda record: record.pk
        }
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover', 'id': 'student_list'}
```

views.py

```
def all_My_Student(request):
    student_list = Student.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    table = StudentListTable(student_list)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'students/all_my_student.html', {'table': table, 'student_list': student_list})
```

all_my_student.html

```
{% block main_content %}
    <div class="box box-primary" id="student_list_table">
        {% if table %}
            {% render_table table %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    {% for student in student_list %}
        <div class="detailed" id="{{ student.id }}">
            {{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_javascript %}
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('.detailed').hide();


            }
        );

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

What I want to do is make a Javascript function that's basically like this: As you can see, the "detailed" class divs are hidden from the start. When you click on a row in the model object table, the "detailed" class div with an id that matches that of the row (or basically corresponds with the same model object in both the table loop and the second loop) will show, and the rest will still be hidden. I hope that it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a sidenote, if the queryset used in the table is the same as `student_list` there is no need to pass `student_list` separately to the template context, you can just use `table.data`.

I would hide the `<div class="detailed">` blocks using CSS, and not using JavaScript, as if you do use JavaScript, they might be visible for a slight moment when the page loads.

You should try to avoid adding `id` attributes to too much html elements. In your example, you add the student id as an `id` attribute to both the table `<tr>`'s and the `<div class="detailed">` elements. The HTML spec [requires ID's to be unique in the whole document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), so if you want to use them, make sure they are unique.

It's better to use data attributes. In the example below, I added the attribute `data-student-id` to both the table row and the `<div class="detailed">` element. You can now select `div[data-student-id="12"]` to get the details div element for student with id = 12:

```
# table.py
class StudentListTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.TemplateColumn('''...''', verbose_name=u'Name')
    manage = tables.TemplateColumn('''....''')

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id', 'name', 'gender', 'ssn', 'email', 'primary_phone', 'created_at', 'manage', 'assign')
        row_attrs = {
            'data-student-id': lambda record: record.pk
        }
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover', 'id': 'student_list'}

{# django template #}
<style>
    .detailed {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

{% for student in table.data %}
    <div class="detailed" data-student-id="{{ student.id }}">
        {{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% block custom_javascript %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#student_list tr').on('click', function () {
            var student_id = $(this).data('student-id');
            $('div[data-student-id="' + student_id + '"]').show();
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Alternatively, you could add the required data to `data-` attributes of the table and create the details view in JavaScript. That maybe would make the generated HTML a bit smaller.

Comment: This works. However, I also want to make it so that any clicks on other rows would make the div from before be replaced with the new div, and to be able to click on a row again to make the div disappear.

Comment: What did you try to achieve that? Do you know about [$(...).toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Yeah, I remembered toggle right after I made that comment. Though I still would like to know how to hide divs that were shown before when I click on another row.

Comment: So what you need to do is: 1. Check if a div is open and if so, get its id. 2. If none is open, just open the one requested. 3. If one is open, close it and open the id of the row clicked. If the id of the open div is equal to the ID of the row clicked, do not open a div.